# Is it possible to save a scan data from DynamoDb to a variable in Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS Lambda function and I am performing read operation from my DynamoDB.
The question is, is it possible to save the data that i retrieved from DynamoDB. Since i want to send one of the values of the field in a write or update operation later.

```
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 
    const params = {
            TableName: 'parking_lots',
            Limit: 10
    }
    return ddb.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    
 
};
```

Something like for example:

```
const data = ddb.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

So i can access a data something like this

```
data.lot_number;
```

Comment: You mean return data to the invoker of the lambda function or save the data to be used by future lambda function invocations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you meant "store" the data in a variable.

It will be easier for you to understand if you use `async/await`.

```js
'use strict';

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

const docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 
    const params = {
            TableName: 'parking_lots',
            Limit: 10
    }

    const data = await ddb.scan(params).promise()
    
    // You now have access to data.
    console.log(data)
    
    return Promise.resolve()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SDK command for dynamo returns a json object. You can do anything with that object, including storing it in memory for later use *in the same invocation*

That data **will not** still be available the next time the lambda is called. They do not keep state between invocations (technically there is a possibility but you should never rely on it because it exists some times and other times it doesn't and it can really mess up other invocations)